# Does codeigniter 3 support PHP 7?

Tags: codeigniter, php-7

In the docs of CodeIgniter it states,

> PHP version 5.4 or newer is recommended.

I looked on forums etc. and wasn't able to find a definitive yes/no on this, even though the above sentence implies a 'yes', I wasn't sure if that extended to the (now new) PHP7.

I have tried a simple CI3 example with PHP7, and all I can report is so good, so far.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using PHP v7 with the latest code igniter on a production environment without extensive testing to ensure that no issues will be encountered. So far, I haven't found any issues which affect my particular setup.

Comment: Why not?  I'd suggest that you haven't had any issues so far because codeigniter *does* support PHP 7.  The last version was 6 days ago and the version before that includes fixes for `count` with PHP 7.2...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes.  The latest [v3.0.4 changelog](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html#version-3-0-4) explicitly has changes to use PHP7 functionality where it can e.g.

> Updated Security Library method get_random_bytes() to use PHP 7’s
>   random_bytes() function when possible.

**Update August 2018**
There's also items in the change log for [3.1.8](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html#bug-fixes-for-3-1-8) which relate to fixes for PHP 7.2, as well as [3.1.7](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html#bug-fixes-for-3-1-7) which specifically mention fixes for PHP 7

Comment: so why does CI still use my_sql (which has been removed in php7) instead my_sqli ?I had to all the my_sql into my_sqli manually.

Comment: It still have the `mysql_` functionality for added support on older PHP versions.  CI3 is built to run on  PHP 5.2.4+.  You shouldn't have needed to change any parts of the driver, you should have just needed to specify the driver to be mysqli (http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html)

Comment: current version is 3.1.8 but still they dont have fully php 7 version .

Answer (score 10):

> yes codeigniter3.1.11 support PHP version 5.6 to latest 7.3.